# How to style mgt components

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap, microsoft-graph-toolkit

I'm using the MGT with React. I am trying to style the  component in the same fashion as the rest of my application (reactstrap).

I've found the custom CSS properties you can set, which has got me 90% of the way there, but I need to be able to adjust the margins of the control (margin-left: -3px) and I can't seem to do this no matter what I try.

I think the answer to my problem lies in using the templating functionality but the documentation is a bit lacking for this.

Any ideas where I should start with this? Am I on the right track? Does anyone know of an example of using templates with the PersonPicker component?

Answer (score 0):

Without specifics, there definitely might some css properties that we haven't exposed yet. I don't think there would be any recommended code to use here, instead I'd highly suggest opening a an [issue](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/issues/new/choose) on our github repo as a feature request. We can then work with you on improving the toolkit with these properties.

Comment: So templates won't help me here?

Comment: Its hard to say, if you have seen our samples (non-react) for [templating](https://mgt.dev/?path=/story/components-mgt-people-picker-templating--person-templates) and the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/components/people-picker#templates) and are having specific trouble, we can't help much without a sample. We try to extend these the best we can, but there are scenarios we can't cover so we'll hope the community brings them forward. Posting this on the repo with screenshots or more info will help.

Comment: Thanks for your help I'll post something soon.